# Custom Post Types and Categories

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I've been trying for days to create a custom post type, with categories. So far, I have this working, and I can add content easily, and assign it to a category. My code is below.

What I don't understand, and can't seem to work is creating an archive page to display posts of a category.
For example: My post type is called **Adverts**. My category is called **Photographers**.

Is it possible for the page to dynamically work out what category you're on and display all custom posts belonging to that category?

```
function my_custom_post_advert() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'               => _x( 'Adverts', 'post type general name' ),
        'singular_name'      => _x( 'Advert', 'post type singular name' ),
        'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'advert' ),
        'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Advert' ),
        'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Advert' ),
        'new_item'           => __( 'New Advert' ),
        'all_items'          => __( 'All Adverts' ),
        'view_item'          => __( 'View Advert' ),
        'search_items'       => __( 'Search Adverts' ),
        'not_found'          => __( 'No adverts found' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No adverts found in the Trash' ), 
        'parent_item_colon'  => '',
        'menu_name'          => 'Adverts'
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels'        => $labels,
        'description'   => 'Holds our adverts and advert specific data',
        'public'        => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'supports'      => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'category' ),
        'has_archive'   => true,
    );
    register_post_type( 'advert', $args );  
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_custom_post_advert' );

function my_taxonomies_advert() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'              => _x( 'Advert Categories', 'taxonomy general name' ),
        'singular_name'     => _x( 'Advert Category', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
        'search_items'      => __( 'Search Advert Categories' ),
        'all_items'         => __( 'All Advert Categories' ),
        'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Advert Category' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Advert Category:' ),
        'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Advert Category' ), 
        'update_item'       => __( 'Update Advert Category' ),
        'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Advert Category' ),
        'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Advert Category' ),
        'menu_name'         => __( 'Advert Categories' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'hierarchical' => true,
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'advert_category', 'advert', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_taxonomies_advert', 0 );
```

Answer (score 2):

You basically need to create a ***page template*** that contains a customized wp_query so WordPress can determine what category you're on.

Once you have your page template created then you can create a page in your WordPress admin ... selecting the new page template as your template.

And if you want the category to be dynamic you could always setup your page template to accept a $_GET parameter to determine which category to display adverts from. Like so:

```
http://example.com/adverts-listing/?mycat=photographers
```

or

```
http://example.com/adverts-listing/?mycat=programmers
```

etc.

Here's an example of what the page template may look like (course this will vary on what theme you're using ... this example was built to use the twentyfourteen theme):

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Advert Listing
 *
 */

get_header(); ?>

  <section id="primary" class="content-area">
    <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">

    <?php
      // Set the args array for the query to happen
      $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'adverts',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => 10
      );

      // Dynamically set the mycat argument from a $_GET parameter
      if( isset($_GET['mycat']) ) {
        $args['tax_query'] => array(
          array(
            'taxonomy' => 'advert_category',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $_GET['mycat']
          )
        );
      }

      // Issue the query
      $q = null;
      $q = new WP_Query($args);

      // Start the loop
      if( $q->have_posts() ) : ?>
        <header class="page-header">
          <h1 class="page-title"><?php _e( 'Advert Listing:', 'twentyfourteen' ); ?></h1>
        </header>

        <?php

        while ($q->have_posts()) : $q->the_post();
          ?>

          <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="post-<?php the_ID(); ?> adverts type-adverts status-publish hentry">

            <header class="entry-header">
              <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(get_the_ID()); ?>"><h3 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h3></a>
            </header><!-- .entry-header -->

            <div class="entry-content">
              <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
            </div>

          </article>

          <?php

        endwhile;

        // Previous/next post navigation.
        twentyfourteen_paging_nav();

      else :
        // If no content, include the "No posts found" template.
        get_template_part( 'content', 'none' );

      endif;

      wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().
      ?>

    </div><!-- #content -->
  </section><!-- #primary -->

<?php

get_sidebar( 'content' );
get_sidebar();
get_footer();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to navigate to /adverts. Also, `has_archive` should create an archives page for you.

Comment: Why isn't this the correct answer? Am I missing something? I don't have any idea what half the answers on this page are talking about!

Answer (score 0):

To save yourself a lot of hassle and what I've used in the past is [this custom post type plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/types/) - it works like a charm:

> Types let's you customize the WordPress admin by adding content types, custom fields and taxonomy. You will be able to craft the WordPress admin and turn it into your very own content management system.

And with that I use this [Custom post type archive plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-type-archives/):

> This plugin will enable custom post type archives (also yearly, monthly and daily) together with feeds, customizable titles and paging.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is essentially contained in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18492797/exclude-category-from-custom-post-type-loop-archive) elsewhere on StackOverflow.

To summarize, build a custom query, but in the $args array replace:

> `'cat_name' => 'Photographers'`

with a taxonomy query, like so:

> `'tax_query' => array(
>       array(
>           'taxonomy' => 'advert_category',
>           'field' => 'slug',
>           'terms' => 'photographers'
>       )
>   )`

Of course, you should include `'post-type' => 'advert'` in $args as well.  Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

So I also had a need for custom post types with categories.

The code below is really simple and clean. Literally **copy and paste**. and then just adjust to your needs. Hope this helps people in the future.

It basically **links the normal wordpress categories with your custom post types.** making it really easy for your client when they are working from the wordpress admin section. It also has individual taxonomy via tags. so **you have the option to have categories through all post types or post specific taxonomy**.

The code is pretty self-explanatory. Please vote for my answer I need to build up my rep. Thank you.

You must copy the code into your **functions.php** file

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_types' );
    function create_post_types() {
// Custom Post 1
        register_post_type( 'companies',
            array(
                'labels' => array(
                    'name' => __( 'Companies' ),
                    'singular_name' => __( 'Company' )
                ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            )
        );
        // Default Wordpress Category Taxonomy
        register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'category', 'companies' );
        // Post Specific Taxonomy
        register_taxonomy( 'company_category', 'companies' );
// Custom Post 2
        register_post_type( 'events',
            array(
                'labels' => array(
                    'name' => __( 'Events' ),
                    'singular_name' => __( 'Event' )
                ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            )
        );
        // Default Wordpress Category Taxonomy
        register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'category', 'events' );
        // Post Specific Taxonomy
        register_taxonomy( 'events_category', 'events' );
// Custom Post 3
        register_post_type( 'deals',
            array(
                'labels' => array(
                    'name' => __( 'Deals' ),
                    'singular_name' => __( 'Deal' )
                ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            )
        );
        // Default Wordpress Category Taxonomy
        register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'category', 'deals' );
        // Post Specific Taxonomy
        register_taxonomy( 'deals_category', 'deals' );
// Custom Post 4
        register_post_type( 'banners',
            array(
                'labels' => array(
                    'name' => __( 'Banners' ),
                    'singular_name' => __( 'Banner' )
                ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            )
        );
        // Default Wordpress Category Taxonomy
        register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'category', 'banners' );
        // Post Specific Taxonomy
        register_taxonomy( 'banners_category', 'banners' );
    }
```

There are 4 custom post types so like I said the code is pretty self-explanatory